# Server side validation with client side forms in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms, express

I have a simple form which takes the name of a menu item and the price of that item and puts that data into a database. In my server, I setup a route where when the program is adding in the menu item, if the name is the same as another name on the menu, it spits out as error via `res.json()` like this:

```
if (newItem) {
    //Add the item to the db
  }
  else {
    // the item has the same name as another item on the menu
    res.json("{\"Error\" : \"Menu Item already exists!\"}");
  }
```

Now I want to show an error in my form when the error object is returned to the client from my server. I have setup my form and the error in my form, but I can't quite get the error to toggle properly when a similar item name is given.

This is my form:

```
<form role="form" name="addMenuItem">
            <div layout="row">
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs="">
                    <label>Item Name</label>
                    <input name="item_name" ng-model="formData.item_name" ng-minlength="1" ng-required="true" size="30">
                    <div ng-messages="addMenuItem.item_name.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">Item name is required</div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-messages="addMenuItem.item_name.$error.exists">
                        <div ng-message="required">Item name exists</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
//other form components
```

So when the server sends the error object, I want to toggle  the message `addMenuItem.item_name.$error.exists` to show up and I wrote this to toggle it, but it's not quite working:

```
 $http.post('/addMenuItem', $scope.formData)
            .then(function (data) {
                const resJson = JSON.parse(data.data);
                "Error" in resJson ? console.log("Error") : console.log("No err");
                console.log(resJson.hasOwnProperty('Error'));
                if(resJson.hasOwnProperty('Error')) {
                    $scope.addMenuItem[item_name].$setValidity('exists'); // error thrown on this line
                }
                else {
                      //add to db
                }

            });
```

When I run that code, the Chrome Dev console spits on this error:

```
ReferenceError: item_name is not defined
```

From what I can decode, looks like it can't find my form(or more specifically my input of `item_name`) for some reason and I can't figure out why. I'd assume that there is a simple way to toggle the error that I have written in the HTML, right?

Answer (score 0):

Reaplce

```
$scope.addMenuItem[item_name].$setValidity('exists');
```

With

```
$scope.addMenuItem["item_name"].$setValidity('exists');
```

item_name is not a valid variable and hence the error.

Comment: So that got rid of the error in the console, but the error still doesn't show up on the form, got anymore ideas?